# mysql 'slow queries log' return a huge number of rows examined but explain seems ok

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-slow-query-log

The sql query

```
# Query_time: 16.536276  Lock_time: 0.000159 Rows_sent: 756  Rows_examined: 8392194
SET timestamp=1555422526;
SELECT c.id AS c__id, c.company_id AS c__company_id, 
        c.ordinary_price AS c__ordinary_price, c.nights AS c__nights, 
        c.food_type AS c__food_type, c.period AS c__period, 
        c.period_desc AS c__period_desc, c.extra AS c__extra, 
        c.coupons_bought AS c__coupons_bought, c.coupon_price AS c__coupon_price, 
        c.coordinates AS c__coordinates, c.best_price AS c__best_price, 
        c.from_price AS c__from_price, c.end_datetime AS c__end_datetime, 
        c.hide_clock AS c__hide_clock, c.hide_discount AS c__hide_discount, 
        c.booking_hotel_id AS c__booking_hotel_id, c.title AS c__title, 
        c.option_people AS c__option_people, c.option_room AS c__option_room, 
        c.option_period AS c__option_period, c.city AS c__city, 
        c2.id AS c2__id, c2.people AS c2__people, c2.room AS c2__room, 
            (  SELECT c8.url AS c8__url 
               FROM campaign_images c8 
               WHERE (c8.campaign_id = c.id 
                 AND  c8.photo_type = 'list') 
               ORDER BY c8.ordering ASC LIMIT 1
            ) AS c__0 
FROM campaign c 
    LEFT JOIN campaign_options c2 ON c.id = c2.campaign_id 
        AND (c2.active = 1) 
    LEFT JOIN city_in_campaign c3 ON c.id = c3.campaign_id 
    LEFT JOIN city c4 ON c3.city_id = c4.id 
    LEFT JOIN company c5 ON c.company_id = c5.id 
    LEFT JOIN campaign_in_category c6 ON c.id = c6.campaign_id 
    LEFT JOIN campaign_in_group c7 ON c.id = c7.campaign_id 
WHERE c.id IN ('13308', '13281', '13265') 
AND (c.status IN ('published') 
AND c.start_datetime <= NOW() 
AND c.end_datetime >= NOW() 
AND c5.id = '2111' 
AND c.id != '14624' 
AND (c7.group_id in (1) 
    OR c7.group_id is NULL
    )
) 
ORDER BY c.coupon_expire_datetime ASC;
```

create table campaign

```
CREATE TABLE `campaign` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `secondary_source_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `source_hotel_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `booking_hotel_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `booking_board_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `booking_rate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ordinary_price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
 `best_price` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `from_price` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `status` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'draft',
 `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'other',
 `deal_status` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'in_progress',
 `coupon_price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
 `cosmote_discount` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `nights` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `period` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `period_desc` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hide_period` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `food_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `stars` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `adults` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `childs` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `extra` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `best_point` varchar(511) DEFAULT NULL,
 `extra_night_price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `high_season_price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `high_season_desc` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
 `high_season_extra_night_price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `family_packages_desc` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `coordinates` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
 `start_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `end_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `coupon_expire_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `min_coupons` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `is_global` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `hide_clock` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `hide_discount` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `hide_purchases` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `booking_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `booking_phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `refresh` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `installments` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `receipt` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `newsletters_sent` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `max_coupons` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `max_coupons_per_user` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `coupons_bought` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `fake_orders` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
 `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `newsletter_title` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
 `linkwise_title` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
 `option_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `option_title_en` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `option_people` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
 `option_room` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
 `option_period` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(1200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `description` text,
 `highlights` text,
 `coupon_instructions` text,
 `show_in_recent_deals` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `youtube_video_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `in_side` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `family` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `send_newsletter` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `resend_newsletter` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `modified_datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `ordering` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `company_id_idx` (`company_id`),
 KEY `user_id_idx` (`user_id`),
 KEY `status_indx` (`status`),
 KEY `str_dt_indx` (`start_datetime`),
 KEY `end_dt_indx` (`end_datetime`),
 KEY `side_indx` (`in_side`),
 KEY `ord_indx` (`ordering`),
 KEY `global_indx` (`is_global`),
 KEY `act_indx` (`active`),
 KEY `coup_expr_index` (`coupon_expire_datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14788 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

create table campaign_options

```
CREATE TABLE `campaign_options` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `coupons_bought` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `name_en` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `people` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `room` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `food` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `period` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `coupon_price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL,
 `extra_night_price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `high_season_price` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT '0.00',
 `high_season_extra_night_price` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `modified_datetime` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 `main` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `family` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `campaign_id_idx` (`campaign_id`),
 KEY `active_indx` (`active`),
 KEY `family_indx` (`family`),
 KEY `main_indx` (`main`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48990 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

create table city_in_campaign

```
CREATE TABLE `city_in_campaign` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `campaign_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `city_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `campaign_id_idx` (`campaign_id`),
 KEY `city_id_idx` (`city_id`),
 KEY `order_indx` (`ordering`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=227176 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

create table city

```
CREATE TABLE `city` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `country_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `is_active` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `modified_datetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `country_id_idx` (`country_id`),
 KEY `is_active_indx` (`is_active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=254 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

create table company

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `ref_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `description` text,
 `logo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `phone_number` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `address` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `coordinates` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `skype_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `icq_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `payment_information` text,
 `extra1` text,
 `extra2` text,
 `extra3` text,
 `video` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
 `checked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `checked_indx` (`checked`),
 KEY `ordering_indx` (`ordering`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2519 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

create table campaign_in_category

```
CREATE TABLE `campaign_in_category` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `created_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `campaign_id_idx` (`campaign_id`),
 KEY `category_id_idx` (`category_id`),
 KEY `order_indx` (`ordering`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=457080 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

create table campaign_in_group

```
CREATE TABLE `campaign_in_group` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `campaign_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `modified_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `camp_group_indx` (`campaign_id`,`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1175 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

**campaign** total rows: 12,657

**campaign_options** total rows: 43,714

**city_in_campaign** total rows: 15,162

**city** total rows: 215

**company** total rows:  1,756

**campaign_in_category** total rows: 38,817

**campaign_in_group** total rows: 395

[image]
[explain of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7T7f.jpg)

Comment: When you ask a question about query optimization, you should run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for any tables referenced by your query, and include the output in your question. Don't make us guess which indexes, data types, and constraints you have.

Comment: i have added "create table" query and total rows for each table

Comment: Please don't use `LEFT` when the 'right' table is required -- This applies to at least c5 and c7.  You check the others.

Answer (score 0):

which ones have index

---

it looks you need composite index because file sorting.

### usage:

```
CREATE INDEX index_name 
ON table_name(c2,c3,c4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting above result because some time o/p of explain gives different result as response of query of prod.
For optimization of query you can't have a fix answer. it varies from case to case. As for this situation I think you need to perform performance testing of this query. You can do this by inserting some records in all referenced table and then checking it's performance using explain.

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT JOIN campaign_in_category c6 ON c.id = c6.campaign_id
```

seems to be totally useless.  But the Optimizer may not realize it.  Remove it and any other dead code.